# Calculate $\iint_D 2x*cos(2(x-y)x) $ where D is a rectangle with corners at (π/6 ,2+ π /6 ), ( π/6,4+ π/6), (π /4,4+ π/4) and (π/4,2+ π/4)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been trying to calculate the double integral:  $\iint_D 2x*cos(2(x-y)x) $ where D is a rectangle with corners at  (π/6 ,2+ π /6 ), ( π/6,4+ π/6),  (π /4,4+ π/4)  and  (π/4,2+ π/4) for a very long time now, but I get stuck and wonder if there is something I'm missing in my solution? It seems very complicated to integrate this function, have I missed out on any simplifying variable substitution (I tried one as you can see below but that didn't make it much easier) or have I approached the problem in the wrong way from the beginning? Down below are my calculations (the figure is very unproportional):

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

/Nick

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of integration so that you integrate with respect to $y$ first?  That looks to me like it would be easier.

Comment: Is your integrand $2x \cos(2x(x-y)) \ dx \ dy$ or $ - 2x  \cos(2x(x-y)) \ dx \ dy$? In the question, it is without the minus sign but in your working, you have a minus sign. I have gone by the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the region is a parallelogram and not a rectangle. The parallelogram is made of two vertical lines $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and you can work out the other two lines as

$y = x + 2$ and $y = x + 4$.

Now change of variable is not necessary if you integrate wrt $y$ first as integral is much simpler then.

$\displaystyle \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} \bigg[\int_{x+2}^{x+4} 2 x \cos(2x^2-2xy) \ dy \bigg] \ dx$

$\displaystyle = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} \big[\sin (2xy-2x^2)\big]_{x+2}^{x+4} \ dx$

$\displaystyle = \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} (\sin 8x - \sin 4x) \ dx$

Can you take it from here?